# How bad is it to simulate IDENTITY/AUTOINCREMENT columns using triggers in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers, primary-key, identity, sequences

I maintain an application that was originally written to be SQL Server-specific (using IDENTITY fields).  Thus, we've had to define a lot of triggers to auto increment tables' primary keys.

I'm told that this is considered to be a hacky workaround in the Oracle world, but that was told to me in a "friend of a friend" kind of way.  How big a deal is it to use triggers to increment primary keys from a sequence instead of using the sequence directly?

Comment: Can you upgrade your Oracle? I think that 10g (or was it 11g?) could already have a sequence in it's DEFAULT, thus eliminating the need for triggers.

Comment: You can't use a sequence as a column default even in 11G as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Yep, no sequence as column default in 11G.  The change in 11G was that within PL/SQL you can now use a sequence as the default value on a variable declaration instead of having to do a select against dual to populate a variable with the sequence nextval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a very common practice in my experience, and not a terribly bad one.  However, if you have control over the inserts (e.g. if all inserts are done via a PL/SQL API) then it is more efficient to use the sequence directly in the INSERT statement - because it avoids the overhead of firing a trigger.  But I really wouldn't worry unduly about it if you have used triggers!

Comment: That's about what I was thinking.  I figured it was just considered "good practice" in much the same manner as closing files instead of not letting them be closed at process end.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be totally relevant, but using "before insert trigger" to auto-increment primary keys is a good option especially in Merge statements. If a sequence is used directly inside Merge insert section, the sequence seems to be invoked even for updates.